# SQLAlchemy: database creation code smaller than database

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, filesize

I have two python files with which I create a database:

One contains all the class declarations, and starts like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, Sequence, Table, ForeignKey, Float, DateTime, ForeignKeyConstraint
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref, relationship, sessionmaker
from os import path

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

genotype_association = Table('gt_association', Base.metadata,
    Column('genotypes_id', Integer, ForeignKey('genotypes.id')),
    Column('animals_id', Integer, ForeignKey('animals.id'))
)
treatment_association = Table('tr_association', Base.metadata,
    Column('chronic_treatments_id', Integer, ForeignKey('chronic_treatments.id')),
    Column('animals_id', Integer, ForeignKey('animals.id'))
)
substance_association = Table('st_association', Base.metadata,
    Column('substance_administrations_id', Integer, ForeignKey('substance_administrations.id')),
    Column('solutions_id', Integer, ForeignKey('solutions.id'))
)
operator_association = Table('op_association', Base.metadata,
    Column('operator_id', Integer, ForeignKey('operators.id')),
    Column('fmri_measurements_id', Integer, ForeignKey('fmri_measurements.id'))
)
ingredients_association = Table('ig_association', Base.metadata,
    Column('solutions_id', Integer, ForeignKey('solutions.id')),
    Column('ingredients_id', Integer, ForeignKey('ingredients.id'))
)
laser_association = Table('ls_association', Base.metadata,
    Column('laser_stimulation_protocols_id', Integer, ForeignKey('laser_stimulation_protocols.id')),
    Column('fmri_measurements_id', Integer, ForeignKey('fmri_measurements.id'))
)

#general classes:

class Operator(Base):
    __tablename__ = "operators"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = Column(String, unique=True)
    full_name = Column(String)
    affiliation = Column(String)

class MeasurementUnit(Base):
    __tablename__ = "measurement_units"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = Column(String, unique=True)
    long_name = Column(String)
    siunitx = Column(String)

class Ingredient(Base):
    __tablename__ = "ingredients"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = Column(String, unique=True)
    name = Column(String)
    concentration = Column(Float, default=100)
    concentration_unit_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('measurement_units.id'))
    concentration_unit = relationship("MeasurementUnit")
    supplier = Column(String)
    supplier_id = Column(String)
    contained = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("ingredients.id"))
    contains = relationship("Ingredient")

class Solution(Base):
    __tablename__ = "solutions"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = Column(String, unique=True)
    name = Column(String)
    supplier = Column(String)
    supplier_id = Column(String)
    contains = relationship("Ingredient", secondary=ingredients_association, backref="ingredient_of")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Solution(name='%s' (long_name='%s'), concentration=%s%s contains: %s)>"\
        % (self.name, self.long_name, self.concentration, self.concentration_unit, self.contains)
```

The other file imports the classes, and creates some entries, starting like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, literal
from os import path
from common_classes import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from add import loadSession, commit_and_close, double_entry
from datetime import datetime

def initialize_main_entries(db_path):
    session,engine = loadSession(db_path)

    christ = Operator(code="Chr", full_name="Horea Christian", affiliation="ETH")

    #Measurement Units
    s = MeasurementUnit(code="s", long_name="second", siunitx="\\second")
    session.add(s)
    g = MeasurementUnit(code="g", long_name="gram", siunitx="\\gram")
    hz = MeasurementUnit(code="Hz", long_name="hertz", siunitx="\\hertz")
    session.add(hz)
    percent = MeasurementUnit(code="%", long_name="percent", siunitx="\\percentt")
    session.add(percent)
    mi = MeasurementUnit(code="min", long_name="minute", siunitx="\\arcminute")
    session.add(mi)
    mg_l = MeasurementUnit(code="mg/l", long_name="milligram per litre", siunitx="\\milli\\gram\\per\\litre")
    mg_ml = MeasurementUnit(code="mg/ml", long_name="milligram per millilitre", siunitx="\\milli\\gram\\per\\milli\\litre")
    mul_g = MeasurementUnit(code="mul/g", long_name="microlitre per gram", siunitx="\\micro\\litre\\per\\gram")

    #Ingredients
    flu = Ingredient(name="Fluoxetine Hydrochloride", concentration="2.25", concentration_unit=mg_ml, supplier="Tocris")
    med = Ingredient(name="Medetomidine", concentration=38.5, concentration_unit=mg_l, supplier="Provert AG, Orion Pharma", supplier_id="DOMITOR")
    sal = Ingredient(name="Sodium Chloride", concentration=86.535, concentration_unit=mg_ml)
    sal_flu = Ingredient(name="Sodium Chloride", concentration=997.75, concentration_unit=mg_ml)
    iso_3 = Ingredient(name="Isoflurane", concentration=3, concentration_unit=percent, supplier="Piramal Healthcare")
    iso_05 = Ingredient(name="Isoflurane", concentration=0.5, concentration_unit=percent, supplier="Piramal Healthcare")
    air = Ingredient(name="Air", concentration=80, concentration_unit=percent)
    oxy = Ingredient(name="Oxygen", concentration=20, concentration_unit=percent)
    e_air_3 = Ingredient(name="Enriched Air", concentration=97, concentration_unit=percent, contains=[air, oxy])
    e_air_05 = Ingredient(name="Enriched Air", concentration=99.5, concentration_unit=percent, contains=[air, oxy])
    rnasea10 = Ingredient(name="RNase A", concentration=10, concentration_unit=mg_ml)
```

These files are 13KB and 28KB respectively - while the databse file they produce is 60KB.

Is this to be expected, or is it indicative of my database structure being messed up?

Comment: The size of your .py source code has nothing to do with the database size.

Comment: But how can information which fits into 28KB of python source code (including all of the imports, function calls, syntax, and comments) end up taking up 60KB in .db format? If anything, I would have expected the .db to make better use of space.

Comment: @Selzuk, I guess the size of the second file could be proportional to the size of the database, but the database would keep more stuff like metadata so it's bound to be higher for small sizes of data. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Databases often have extra space declared too, eg for indexes. This will show up as "used space" but it in fact still unused. The reason being that indexes need some slack space to fast fill in new entries.

Comment: Each database has its own way of storing data, some more efficient, some not so much. You can learn more about SQLite file structure for an example: https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite database files are organized into pages (with the default page size probably being 4 KB), and tables or indexes cannot share pages.
Therefore, you will need at least one page for each database object.

New rows will be able to use the free space in these pages, so inserting the first few records will not increate the database file size.